# Problem with BSC full node

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nodes, ubuntu, full-node

I try install full node Binance Smart Chain (https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html). I follow all the instructions on the site.

After the command

```
geth --config ./config.toml --datadir ./node -pprof.addr 0.0.0.0 --metrics --pprof
```

I get messages

```
ERROR[04-08|14:47:00.953] Unavailable modules in HTTP API list     unavailable=[parlia] available="[admin debug web3 eth txpool personal ethash miner net]"
WARN [04-08|14:47:33.190] Invalid header encountered               number=1       hash="040553…2ad0f6" parent="0d2184…d57b5b" err="extra-data too long: 97 > 32"
INFO [04-08|14:47:33.190] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0 blockTasks=0 itemSize=0.00B throttle=8192
WARN [04-08|14:47:33.190] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=6c7bc767b533972a12b605c1f086c6503df257cb91296bed6faaae3dcc2ef5a8 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid: extra-data too long: 97 > 32"
```

I don't understand how i can fix it. I saved and unziped this snapshot (https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/validator/snapshot.html) but it not work.

I install get from /bsc folder (1.10.1-stable-c2d2f4ed).
Please, help me.

Comment: By the way, you linked a page relating to Binance CHain, not Binance Smart Chain (BSC). They are 2 different blockchains.

Comment: git clone https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc;
cd bsc;
make all;

I did this commands, what i should rename?

Comment: Why? I use https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html, it is Binance Smart Chain if i understand

Comment: @Undead8, help please.

Answer (score 1):

@Unhead8, i did this steps:

1. mkdir bsc
2. wget  https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/releases/download/v1.0.7/geth_linux
3. wget   $(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/binance-chain/bsc/releases/latest |grep browser_ |grep mainnet |cut -d" -f4)
4. unzip mainnet.zip
5. geth --datadir node init genesis.json
6. geth --config ./config.toml --datadir ./node

But i get errorrs

```
ERROR[04-09|08:28:14.062] Unavailable modules in HTTP API list     unavailable=[parlia] available="[admin debug web3 eth txpool personal ethash miner net]"
INFO [04-09|08:28:14.064] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8545 prefix= cors= vhosts=localhost
INFO [04-09|08:28:14.106] Initialized state bloom                  items=25 errorrate=0.000 elapsed=53.250ms
INFO [04-09|08:28:14.794] New local node record                    seq=2 id=6dc53e10d69a5ce5 ip=138.68.86.198 udp=30311 tcp=30311
INFO [04-09|08:28:24.419] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=125 static=23
ERROR[04-09|08:28:26.146] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=98998f1a err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
INFO [04-09|08:28:35.024] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=120 static=23
INFO [04-09|08:28:39.004] Block synchronisation started
WARN [04-09|08:28:40.974] Node data write error                    err="trie node 65bc0c…a126f6 failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
INFO [04-09|08:28:40.975] Downloader queue stats                   receiptTasks=0 blockTasks=0 itemSize=0.00B throttle=8192
WARN [04-09|08:28:40.975] Synchronisation failed, retrying         err="trie node 65bc0c…a126f6 failed with all peers (2 tries, 2 peers)"
```